# GTK: Ignore/suppress key events when user is editing some text field

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I have a simple GTK application that has one `Window`, which contains one `TreeView`. I Created one `TreeViewColumn` for it, whose `CellRendererText` is `editable`.

So when the user double clicks on a row in the `TreeView`, he is able to edit the text.

However, I also subscribe to key events (`connect_key_press_event` on the `Window`), and aim to provide hotkeys such as Backspace to do some certain action.

The problem is that I still get key events while the user is editing a row. So for example when the user presses Backspace while editing a row, is there any way for me to either know whether a user is currently editing something, so that I can ignore the key event, or suppress key events while the user is editing?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3878872/3510424) on SO, it is relevant to your question. You may also be able to detect if the window has focus, and only interpret the Backspace (or other keys) as a shortcut when the window has focus.

Comment: `gtk_window_get_focus ()` returns the current focused widget (see the [GTK Docs](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-get-focus) - You can check if the returned widget is a text field, and based on that decide if you want to handle the backspace or ignore it.

Comment: Thanks! I succeeded by checking that `gtk_window_get_focus()` was a `CellEditable`.

Comment: Awesome! Since you've solved the problem, you could answer your own question and mark it solved, or if you'd prefer I can answer the question - either way since the problem is solved you should accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to check `gtk_window_get_focus()` - if it is a `CellEditable` then the user is typing in a text field it seems.